# Objects in an immutable class as member variable

Tags: java, immutability

I have a class X which holds Employee object. I want to make the class X as immutable. Now even if I declare the Employee object as final the Employee class exists independently and people can access the setter methods of that particular employee object. Is it possible to have a normal class Employee and another immutable class X which holds Employee but we cannot change value of Employee once it is assigned?

```
public final class X {

private final Employee emp;

public X (Employee e){
   this.emp = e;

}
public Employee getEmp(){

return emp;

}

}
```

The employee class I dont want to make it immutable, just want to make the class X as immutable.Hence once an employee is assigned it should not be allowed to change it.
Is that possible without making the class Employee as immutable.
I want class Employee to exist independently so do not want to privatize its construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to expose the Employee member of the immutable class. You can introduce getter methods that would expose only relevant fields of the Employee.

```
public final class X {

  private final Employee emp;

  public X (Employee e){
     this.emp = e.clone ();
  }

  public String getEmpName(){
    return emp.getName();
  }

  public int getEmpSalary(){
    return emp.getSalary();
  }

}
```

Of course, there's one more thing you have to do to ensure the class is really immutable. The constructor should create a copy of the Employee passed to it. Otherwise, the caller of the constructor would still have a reference to the Employee, and would be able to change that object.

Comment: Others could theoretically still change the instance which was handed in via the constructor, so this is no 100% safe solution

Comment: Hey Eran , It all makes sense now. Thanks for the info. So if I dont return the user with the emp object he cant do any modification.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an copy constructor to Employee and use it whenever an instance of it is passed into or out of your immutable class.

```
public final class X {

    private final Employee emp;

    public X (Employee e){
       this.emp = new Employee(e);

    }
    public Employee getEmp(){
      return new Employee(emp);
    } 
}
```

Having said this, you should still seriously re-evaluate if you better would make Employee immutable, too, as all this copying could have quite some overhead.

Comment: Thanks for this option as well. I was just curious about this design. If i need to implement it will keep whatever you've said in mind.